# Nodejs Op sequelize multiple relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 4 tables "User", "Teacher", "Address", "Subjects" the User table have connection to Teacher table (userId field) and the Teacher table have connection to "Address", and "Subjects" (teacherId)

what I want is to map all users that has a data of teacher, address and subjects, my problem is I cant connect the address and subjects table to users

this is my current code

```
async getUsersTeacherInfo(){
  let user = await Database.getConnection().models.User
  let teacher = await Database.getConnection().models.Teacher
  let address = await Database.getConnection().models.Address
  let subjects = await Database.getConnection().models.Subjects
  user.hasOne(teacher, { foreignKey: 'userId', sourceKey: '_id' })
  user.belongsTo(address, { foreignKey: 'teacherId', sourceKey: '_id' })
  user.belongsTo(subjects, { foreignKey: 'teacherId', sourceKey: '_id' })
  user = await Database.getConnection().models.User.findAll({
    attributes:[....,],
    include:[
        { model: Teacher, attributes: ['status', 'Teacher','_id'] },
        { model: Address, attributes: [....,], paranoid: false,   required: false},
        { model: Subjects, attributes: [....,], paranoid: false,   required: false},
    ]

  })

}
```

I've tried also this

```
    async getUsersTeacherInfo(){
      let user = await Database.getConnection().models.User
      let teacher = await Database.getConnection().models.Teacher
      let address = await Database.getConnection().models.Address
      let subjects = await Database.getConnection().models.Subjects
      user.hasOne(teacher, { foreignKey: 'userId', sourceKey: '_id' })
      user.belongsTo(address, { foreignKey: 'teacherId', sourceKey: '_id' })
      user.belongsTo(subjects, { foreignKey: 'teacherId', sourceKey: '_id' })
      user = await Database.getConnection().models.User.findAll({
        attributes:[....,],
        include:[
            { model: Teacher, attributes: ['status', 'Teacher','_id'], 

               include:[
                     { model: Address, attributes: [....,], paranoid: false,   required: false},
                    { model: Subjects, attributes: [....,], paranoid: false,   required: false},

           ]}
        ]
    
      })
    
    }
```

Comment: what is `model: Techer` isn't it `model: Teacher` ?

Comment: Teacher, sorry for typo

Comment: Can you share your tables schema? Your associations doesn't look right. Use this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support